# Plot secondary data as ticks on a second y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot secondary data, not as a plot, but as a y-axis.
I have tried to make it clear in the figure.
First I've plotted A versus C.

Now I would like to plot A versus B, but not as a line, but as numbers coinciding with A. 
A in this case is depth. In depth there have been two measurements B and C. I have already plotted the relationship between A and C as a line-plot. Now I would like to add the relationship of A and B as a sort of table into the secondary y-axis. 
Note: I do not need a secondary y-axis! I need the value of B(A=2), B(A=0), B(A=-2) etc. to be noted as a number in a second y-axis. So only the ticks of A have to get a number B(A) in the second axis.

```
          0 -              +   - 0
         -1 -             +    - 0.5
         -2 -            +     - 0.62
         -3 -           +      - 2.1
       A -4 -          +       - 1.5  B
         -5 -       +++        - 1.9
         -6 -     +            - 2.8
         -7 -  +               - 3.0
         -8 - +                - 4.1
            --------------------
                       C
```

[example][1]

I have implemented the example of Stefan, but with lists instead of a function. (`dpt[0]` = `a[0]` = `c[0]`, `dpt[22]` = `a[22]` = `c[22]`, etc.)
My lists are long and have many decimals. Therefor my tick-values do not exactly correspond to the data in the lists. I found the nearest value and rounded the numbers. For the ones who are interested, this works for me:

```
    ax2 = ax1.twinx() 
    depth = [round(x, 1) for x in dpt]  # In my case the original list used 5 decimals and next line ‘difr’ has 1 decimal.
    def mapAtoB(A):
        difr= min(depth, key=lambda x: abs(x - A))   #Find the value in ‘depth’ which is closest to the tick-value A.
        B = round(a[depth.index(difr)],2)            #The index value (difr==depth) is plugged into the list I want on the y-axis. The obtained value needed to be rounded as well. 
        return B

    ax2.plot(c, dpt, alpha=0)
    ticks = ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda dpt, pos: '{0:g}'.format(mapAtoB(dpt)))
    ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticks)
```

I hope my example is clear enough!

Comment: How can I make this graph with A = [1, 2, 3, ...], B= [2, 4, 8, 16,..) and C= [3, 9, 27, 81, ....]. All same length and A(0) corresponds to B(0) and C(0). A(22) corresponds to B(22) and C(22) etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

As you presumably know how `A` maps to `B`, simply transform the y-ticks from A to y-ticks of B, plot both and hide the plot for B.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

def mapAtoB(A):
    B = A**2
    return B

x = [1,2,3,4,5]

y = np.power(x,2)


fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.grid()
ax1.plot(x,y, marker = 'X')
ax1.set_xlabel('x-axis')
ax1.set_yticks(y)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(x, y, alpha=0)
ax2.set_yticks(y)
ticks = ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{0:g}'.format(mapAtoB(x)))
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticks)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]